# How to deploy to dedicated server using circleci

Tags: node.js, circleci, circleci-2.0

I am very new to CircleCi and trying to deploy a node/npm/vue app to plesk on contabo where domain is on a dedicated IP. The error has the following details.

```
ls -al rsync -a dist/* $SSH_USER@$SSH_HOSTNAME:/var/www/vhosts/mydomain.com/domain.com total 524
drwxrwxr-x  7 circleci circleci   4096 Sep 16 12:50 .
drwxr-xr-x 16 circleci circleci   4096 Sep 16 12:50 ..
-rw-rw-r--  1 circleci circleci     66 Sep 16 12:50 babel.config.js
drwxrwxr-x  2 circleci circleci   4096 Sep 16 12:50 .circleci
drwxr-xr-x  6 circleci circleci   4096 Sep 16 12:49 dist
drwxrwxr-x  8 circleci circleci   4096 Sep 16 12:50 .git
-rw-rw-r--  1 circleci circleci    230 Sep 16 12:50 .gitignore
-rw-rw-r--  1 circleci circleci    107 Sep 16 12:50 jsconfig.json
-rw-rw-r--  1 circleci circleci   1533 Sep 16 12:50 package.json
-rw-rw-r--  1 circleci circleci 481935 Sep 16 12:50 package-lock.json
drwxrwxr-x  2 circleci circleci   4096 Sep 16 12:50 public
-rw-rw-r--  1 circleci circleci    329 Sep 16 12:50 README.md
drwxrwxr-x  8 circleci circleci   4096 Sep 16 12:50 src
-rw-rw-r--  1 circleci circleci     59 Sep 16 12:50 vue.config.js
ssh: connect to host ************* port 22: Connection timed out rsync: connection unexpectedly closed (0 bytes received so far) [sender] rsync error: unexplained error (code 255) at io.c(226) [sender=3.1.0]

Exited with code exit status 255  CircleCI received exit code 255
```

Why am I getting this error and how do I resolve it?